# Why update "language" the first time you install Gnome in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

I have been playing with Arch linux install lately. I tried to install vanilla arch through command prompt and use a distro like Gnome for the GUI. However whenever I login into the system I am unable to install any program say for eg terminal or neofetch.

Later I figured that I have to change the language to "english" and the packages startef installing without any trouble. have you even experienced this issue ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: You need to provide more details, like an error message, for us to help you. At the moment, the best we can do is guess.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This issue is already closed

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo your locale into `/etc/locale.conf` for GNOME to load the correct language and work out of the box. Next time you install GNOME with Arch, do `echo 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8'>/etc/locale.conf` or else you will find that the language is set to `Unspecified` on `gnome-control-center` just like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAg5Y.jpg).

Comment: Many thanks. This is exactly the screen I got too. I will do that today 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8'>/etc/locale.conf  I thought i did that, but may be I am wrong. Let me try to reinstall Arch again, and report the progress. Many thanks again and have a nice day